# Creating batch file to open Visual Studio command prompt?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-line, msbuild

I have tried something like this but did not work:

```
@echo off
call "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC"
mstest /testcontainer: mytest.dll
```

save as .bat file and when i double click it does nothing.

So, I am trying to open command prompt located in visual studio and execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to change the directory to `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC"`?

Try this:

```
@echo off
CD "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC"
mstest /testcontainer: mytest.dll
PAUSE
```

Comment: Add a `PAUSE` command at the end so you can see the error message.

Comment: does not work meaning, it does not execute the next step which is `mstest /testcontainer.....`

Comment: Does the command prompt stay open? Is there an error message displayed?

Comment: Is there anything else in your batch file? Put an `ECHO test` statement just before the `PAUSE`. It should write the word `test` to the screen.

Comment: @Both: TBH I would put an `ECHO` before **and** after the `mstest` instructions.  Also, it may be a good idea to redirect any output from the `mstest` command to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Your batch file seems to be a little out of shape there.  I'm no expert, but you have:

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008\VC\"
```

...but without a batch file name.  [See this for info](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/call.php).

If `mstest` is your batch file name then the call should be more like:

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008\VC\mstest.bat " <arguments>
```

Comment: no no, `mstest` is a command i am executing right after i open the command propmt, as a side note you are calling batch file with-in the batch file?

Comment: Ah!  I thought, with the `CALL` in the file, that you were actually calling another batch file from within this one.